# Can I call a WCF service without setting content-type?

Tags: xml, wcf, rest, content-type, webhttpbinding

I'm trying to replace a legacy REST/plain old xml web service with a WCF one using webHttpBinding. It MUST be backwards compatible with existing clients - which currently do not send a content-type header in the requests.

When I point my clients at my new web service I get HTTP ERROR 415 - missing content type.

Is it possible to configure WCF so it will accept raw requests without a content-type header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under .net 3.5 the answer is NO. It seems that content-type is incorectly validated at the transport layer, instead of the application layer. The only way to get around this is to use a custom binding with a custom HtppTransportChannel.

This bug is fixed in .net 4.0

Answer (score 1):

415 is not "missing content type", it is [415 Unsupported Media Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.16).  That infers that the server IS receiving a content-type, it just does not know how to handle it.  According to the HTTP spec, proving a content-type is a SHOULD. not a MUST, so the WCF SHOULD accept a request with no content-type.  If it doesn't, maybe you want to consider using the newer [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com) because they do follow the HTTP spec and allow you to pass content without a content-type header.

---

update:

Apparently this was a bug in earlier version of the .Net framework and there is a workaround/fix https://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/475964/content-type-header-validated-at-the-transport-level-instead-of-the-application-level-and-trows-a-415-exception

Comment: I have tried the solution in the above article, however it only solves the situation where WCF incorrectly handles the content-type on a POST. It does not resolve the issue if there is no content-type header.

Comment: Are you using .Net 4 or 3.5 ?

Comment: 3.5 - this bug is fixed in .net 4.0. 

http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/475964/content-type-header-validated-at-the-transport-level-instead-of-the-application-level-and-trows-a-415-exception

this poster apparently solved the issue by writing a custom HttpTransportChannel and HttpListener,  but this seems like a lot of  effort to fix what seems like a simple problem.