# WCF returns HTTP 400 when Content-Type is not Set to application/json in Postman, else it works fine.

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, iis, content-type

I am looking to build a WCF which can receive, process and return back a JSON. But i want is to work even if the Content-Type of the Http request is not set to application/json.[that is how the requesting system sends in the request]

My Contract looks like below:

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/MethodName", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

I test this wcf service via postman. When i send the HTTP content-type as application/json it works perfectly fine. But for some reason the system that calls my wcf doesn't send that explicitly. So if i disable the content-type in the postman client i get a HTTP 400.

I am hosting this on IIS7. Should i need to specify anything there?

What can i do to make my WCF accept a request that is not explicitly set to a content-type:application/json.

Comment: I also tried to change to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. [HTTP 1.1 specification:](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1), Content-Type it's not mandatory.

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
>   Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and
>   only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
>   recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
>   content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
>   resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
>   treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

but its look like wcf `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` doesn't work. you had to specify the content-type in header. here you can read more about that: [Can I call a WCF service without setting content-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054674/can-i-call-a-wcf-service-without-setting-content-type)